# how can I create role groups in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can create a role in postgresql.

- `CREATE ROLE myname WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'pass';`

and I can set privilages on a database schema for this user.

- `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO myname;`

and select privilages to a user.

- `GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myname;`

But I have so many users in my database. I do not want to set these privilages to all of my users. Actually I want to create role groupnames:

- viewer
- editor
- admin

And 
`viewer` will be select privilages on all tables,
`editor` will be select, insert and update privilages on all tables.

my users will be in these groups.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
CREATE ROLE viewer;
CREATE ROLE editor;
CREATE ROLE admin;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO viewer;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO viewer;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE ON TABLES TO editor;
GRANT some_other_privs_to_admin_group
```

after that just grant group to user:

```
GRANT editor TO your_user;
```

and so on

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html

> CREATE ROLE adds a new role to a PostgreSQL database cluster. A role
>   is an entity that can own database objects and have database
>   privileges; a role can be considered a “user”, a “group”, or both
>   depending on how it is used.

and

> A role having the LOGIN attribute can be thought of as a user. Roles
>   without this attribute are useful for managing database privileges

Comment: yes - grant what ever you want to group to apply to all users that are members of the group (group is granted to user)

Comment: is need to LOGIN to viewer and editor? or login to only myname user?

Comment: updated answer to reflect it. LOGIN is needed for users only - roles usually are not permitted to login

Comment: does prostgresql version (9.4, 9.5) matter in this solution?

Comment: `GRANT <group-role> TO <role>;` was the key for me, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For this very reason it is advisable to use "groups", that is roles (usually with `NOLOGIN`) to which you add the users (by granting the role to them).

In your case:

```
CREATE ROLE viewer;
GRANT <whatever> TO viewer;
GRANT viewer TO myname;
```

Then `myname` will enjoy all the privileges granted to `viewer`, and you don't have to mess around with granting and revoking privileges to every user.